# How to emit the response streamed by a sensor using Socket.io, node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an URL which is streaming data from sensor like temperature and humidity. Now if my API get a call on specific route using socket.io, I need to get the stream of data and show that in a graph on client side dashboard. I was confused on how to fetch the responses from the URL of my sensor and how to display as charts on dashboard. The following is my sample code which returns date, hours, minutes and seconds continuously as a json object. I want to get the dynamic response of sensor data as json objects to stream in socket emit function.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
const server = require('http').createServer();
var link = "http:www.xample.com/usr/api/data/:deviceId";
server.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Server Listening on port: "+port);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection',function(socket){
setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit('date', 
    {
        'date': new Date().getDate(),
        'hour': new Date().getHours(),
        'minutes': new Date().getMinutes(),
        'seconds': new Date().getSeconds()
    });           
}, 1000);

socket.emit("welcome","Socket Connection is successful!");
});

const iot = require('socket.io-client');
let socket = iot.connect("http://localhost:3000");
socket.on("date",function(data){
    console.log(data);
});

socket.on("welcome",function(data){
    console.log("Connection Status: ", data);
});
```

Comment: For your server you can try 

`socket.on('temperature', (data) => {socket.emit('client', data);})`

and for client:

`socket.on('client', (data) => {console.log(data)});`

Comment: Is the above code(my sample code) correct? If you dont mind, can you please edit in the above code and post that. Please. I didn't get your code. (data) refers to what? How could I get the response from my link?

Comment: I've posted some sample code you can use to get started. Check it out and let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Hey @radihuq, please see this link too. Sockets are working fine but there is an issue. So, I've raised one more question. Please have a look. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767686/how-to-stop-the-duplication-of-data-on-client-side-of-socket-io-if-there-is-no-d`

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend reading up on the Socket.io [Client API Docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) and [Server API Docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/)

Sample code you can start with:

Client.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket;

const Client = () => {

    const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState(0);
    const [humidity, setHumidity] = useState(0);

    if (!socket) {
        socket = io('https://localhost:8080', {
            path: '/sensorInfo' 
        });

        socket.on('temperatureChange', (value) => {
            setTemperature(value);
        });

        socket.on('humidityChange', (value) => {
            setHumidity(value);
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>The temperature logged is: {temperature}</p>
            <p>The humidity logged is: {humidity}</p>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Client;
```

Sensor.js:

```
const handleTemperatureChange = (v) => {
    let temperature = v;
    socket.emit('temperatureChange', {temperature});
}

const handleHumidityChange = (v) => {
    let humidity = v;
    socket.emit('humidityChange', {humidity});
}
```

This is definitely not a full solution as it really depends on your system design but hopefully it's enough to get started.

Comment: Thanks @radihuq. But actually I need to have sensor.js file code in which I should have to read the sensor data using the URL written in my sample code above. I dont have to show them in the html page.