# How to use socket.io to reflect one api changes in another api without loading?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I've a node api(POST)in which the sensor keep on pushing the data to the MongoDB. Now I've an api(GET) which fetches the data from the database and displays on the dashboard. To get the continuous stream of data, I want to use SOCKET.IO module. But the problem is, how could I get the recently saved record from the db and show that on dashboard without reloading the page. Please have a look at my code.

**SERVER.JS**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
// and manything like router, middleware, etc...    

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on port:3000');
});
```

**ROUTES FILE**

```
var router = require("express").Router();
router.post("/upload/device/data/:tempId", TemplateController.AddDeviceData); //To insert the data to the DB
router.get("/view/template/device/logs/:tempUniqID", TemplateController.deviceLogs);  //To get the data from DB
```

**TEMPLATE CONTROLLER FILE**

```
module.exports={
    AddDeviceData:async function(req, res){ //Controller to post data
       let err, deviceLog;

       [err, deviceLog]=await     
    to(TemplateService.AddDeviceLogs(req.params.tempId, req.body));
        if(err) return res.serverError(err.message);
        if(deviceLog&&deviceLog!==false){
            return res.ok(deviceLog);
        }else{
            res.badRequest("Sorry cannot add Device log data");
        }
    },

    deviceLogs: async function(req, res){ //Controller to fetch data
        let err, logs;
        let deviceId = req.query.device;
        [err, logs]=await to(TemplateService.displayLogs(req.params.tempUniqID, deviceId));
        if(err) return res.serverError(err.message);
        if(logs&&logs!==false){
            return res.ok(logs);
        }else{
            res.badRequest("Sorry cannot add Device log data");
        }
    }
}
```

**TEMPLATE SERVICE FILE**

```
module.exports={
    //Service to post data
    AddDeviceLogs:async function(templateId, payload){
        let err, deviceData;
        payload.template=templateId;
        const myCollection=templateId;

        [err, deviceData]=await to(mongoose.connection.db.collection(myCollection).insert(payload));
        if(err) TE(err.message, true);
        socket.emit('data', deviceData);
        return (deviceData)? deviceData.result:false;
    },

    //Service to get data
    displayLogs:async function(tempUniqID, deviceID){
        let err, respData;

        var Query = (deviceID)? {"template": tempUniqID, "deviceId": deviceID}:{template: tempUniqID};
        [err, respData]=await to(mongoose.connection.db.collection(tempUniqID).find(Query).sort({_id: -1}).limit(20).toArray())
        if(err) {TE(err, true);}
        return (respData)? respData:false;
    }
}
```

Now I want to get most recently stored data in GET api using socket without reloading the page or without executing the GET route-api. I'm not getting which service I should use server socket-emit event in and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run node and your socket io in the same port, the following example used express and socket.io. I also created sensor code to imagine this solution:

You should use your route file like this:

**ROUTES FILE**

```
var router = require("express").Router();
router.post("/upload/device/data/:tempId", TemplateController.AddDeviceData);
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('C:/Users/user/Desktop/data.html');
})
```

In MVC you will have a root file declare all works, you should delare your socket here.

Because in your codebase, every time you call AddDeviceLogs function, it will re-declare websocket, and your socket client in html file will disconnect, that's why it only work for the first time.

Then you should declare it global, for example:

**server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
// and manything like router, middleware, etc...    

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on port:3000');
});
```

**TEMPLATE SERVICE FILE**

```
module.exports={
    AddDeviceLogs:async function(templateId, payload){
        let err, deviceData;
        payload.template=templateId;
        const myCollection=templateId;

        io.emit('data', payload)  // emit to all client

        [err, deviceData]=await to(mongoose.connection.db.collection(myCollection).insert(payload));
        if(err) TE(err.message, true);
        return (deviceData)? deviceData.result:false;
    }
}
```

**data.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/",{"forceNew": true});
        socket.on('data', function(data){
            if (data) {
                $('#deviceid').text(data.deviceId);
                $('#heat').text(data.heat);
                $('#humidity').text(data.humidity);
            }
        });

        </script>
        <h4>Welcome to socket.io testing program!</h4>
        <div id="deviceid"></div>
        <div id="heat"></div>
        <div id="humidity"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @lamtacvu. But how socket would call the AddDeviceLogs function as it is a service gets executed by the server? The sensor will continuously pushes the data to the db using this service. Every time there is a payload from server, this AddDeviceLogs service gets executed and before saving into the db, socket sending the data to the client. This AddDeviceLogs service has it's own controller and api route. By the way, is html correct?

Comment: @Aravind . I dont have any exp with sensor, but i will assume your system will work as follow: Your sensor connect to your websocket server, your sensor will continuously push data to server, your server will save to database and also sent data to any html client connected. Is it right?.If it is right, let me know then i will edit my answer to this assumption. Your question about your html, nope it is not really correct, you can combine all  socket.on('data', function(data){}) into one.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But do I need to run node server and sockets on different ports? If yes, what would be the way to do that? Can you please correct my html too?

Comment: @Aravind , you can run node server and sockets on the same port. I updated my answer please check them.

Comment: Thanks @lamtacvu. Really appreciate your help with this issue. But I didn't get the solution yet. Even I've updated my code above. Please see that. I'm using MVC architecture. How to use your code in my service? And there is no such file as sensor.js. The data is coming as a payload along with templateId thorugh the above route.

Comment: Sensor is remotely placed and has it's own code written in C in it. For every second, it just sends the data as payload to node server using the route above. I need to change that data in html for every second. The only connection between sensor and node server is the TEMPLATE ID and the ROUTE with which it sends the data.

Comment: The problem is, whenever I run the above route in POSTMAN software, I'm getting the data on html for the first time. But from 2nd time on wards, if I tried to run that route again, the data is not updating on html. So for only one time, it's giving the answer.

Comment: My example of sensor.js is just one example of how system work, i know sensor will have codebase in C or python, but i assume your sensor will connect by socket protocol. So your sensor using http post, right ? If true, then you can define a route in server.js and call AddDeviceLogs in that.

Comment: So, you are using MVC, then i will use your codebase in new edited answer.